# Flask-SqlAlchemy views reflection

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy class has the method reflect:

```
 reflect(bind='__all__', app=None)

    Reflects tables from the database.
```

It has only 2 arguments: bind and app. I don't find any views in `metadata.tables`.

Native SqlAlchemy's method reflect has more arguments and views=False is one of them allowing Views reflection if set up to True.

```
reflect(bind=None, schema=None, views=False, only=None, extend_existing=False, autoload_replace=True, **dialect_kwargs)
```

Is it possible to somehow reflect database views in Flask-SqlAlchemy?

Comment: Thanks to this question for pointing in the right direction for why SQLAlchemy wasn't detecting views by default in the reflection call. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect.params.views  Serious brain fart not RTFM moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass the SQLAlchemy class and override that function.  This is an accepted method of customization in the Flask realm.  The Flask docs themselves talk about subclassing the Flask class to get what you need.

This isn't tested, but here's a start.  It allows kwargs to be passed to execute and reflect, passing them on to the real op.

```
class MySQLAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def _execute_for_all_tables(self, app, bind, operation, **kwargs):
        app = self.get_app(app)

        if bind == '__all__':
            binds = [None] + list(app.config.get('SQLALCHEMY_BINDS') or ())
        elif isinstance(bind, basestring) or bind is None:
            binds = [bind]
        else:
            binds = bind

        for bind in binds:
            tables = self.get_tables_for_bind(bind)
            op = getattr(self.Model.metadata, operation)
            op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), tables=tables, **kwargs)

    def reflect(self, bind='__all__', app=None, **kwargs):
        self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'reflect', **kwargs)
```