# SQLALchemy - cannot reflect a SQL Server DB running on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

My code is simple:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.metadata.reflect()
```

And it throws no errors. However, when I inspect the metadata after this reflection, it returns an empty immutabledict object.

The parameters in my connection string is 100% correct and the code works with non-RDS databases.

It [seems to happen to others as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3ptieu/anyone_ever_connect_to_aws_rds_with_sqlalchemy/) but I can't find a solution.

Also, I have tried to limit the reflection to specific tables using the "only" parameter in the metadata.reflect function, and this is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not reflect: requested table(s) not available in mssql+pyodbc://{connection_string}: (users)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it. The reflect() method of the SQLAlchemy class has a parameter named 'schema'. Setting this parameter, to "dbo" in my case, solved it.

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, which does not have the said parameter in its reflect() method. You can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292931/flask-sqlalchemy-views-reflection) to gain access to that parameter and others, such as 'only'.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when reflect is called without the schema name provided. For example, this will cause the error to happen:

```
metadata.reflect(only = [tableName])
```

It needs to be updated to use the schema of the table you are trying to reflect over like this:

```
metadata.reflect(schema=schemaName, only = [tableName])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set schema='dbo' in parameter for reflect.

```
db.Model.metadata.reflect(bind=engine, schema='dbo', only=['User'])
```

and then create model of your table:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['dbo.User']
```

and to access data from that table: